# What Mr A had at the start of usage of shampoo given the following conditions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Mr. A starts using shed and shoulder shampoo. due to work pressure he lost 
>   1/4th of his hair every year. after how many years will he having 25% less 
>   hair than what he had at the start of usage of shampoo?

options:

A) 3

B) 4

C) 5

D) 7

My Approach:

let Mr.A has x amount of hair...

for 1st yr end he has (x- x/4) = 3x/4

for 2nd yr end he has (3x/4 - 3x/16) = 9x/16

for 3rd yr end he has ( 9x/10 - 9x/64) = 27x/64

or 4th yr end he has (27x/64 - 27x/256) = 81x/256

for 5th yr end he has (81x/256 - 81x/1024) = 243x/1024

Comment: Try to think of the problem in another way. What proportion of his hair does he retain every year?

Comment: I think the question has gotten garbled.  Losing 1/4th of his hair is the same as having 25% less hair.  You seem to interpret 25% *less* hair as meaning 25% hair left (compared to what he had at the beginning).

Comment: Or "less than 25%"

Answer (score 1):

If it's as what hardmath has described, then the problem is 
$$\left(\frac 34\right)^n<0.25=\frac 14\\
n\log(3/4)<\log(1/4)\\
n\log(4/3)>\log(4/1)\\
n>\frac{\log4}{\log4-\log3}=4.8\\
n=5$$

Mr A should use a different shampoo!